# Documentum Captiva Designer Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: captiva, captiva-designer

I am working on Captiva designer for a flow where I need to take help of C# scripting.

From the time I have added the custom script I am getting the following error when opening the flow

[image]

And when I click on "delete external script", flow opens, however on doing any activity like compiling the flow or setting up, it shows the following error!

[image]

Even after clicking "continue", it gets stuck at the following screen

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Emc.InputAccel.ScriptingHost.ScriptingHost.BuildProjectInternal(String projName)
```

Earlier I was able to resolve it by following hotfix, but its not correct way and also it stopped working now!

"whenever I launch the flow, I would go to custom script, and delete whatever code I wrote(only method and class names would remain, which were created by Captiva itself). Then after saving it, I was able to compile it successfully. Then I would paste my custom code back into the script section and same code would compile magically!!"

Note: I am pretty much aware of the Null Point Exception and checked everything in the code, even if it is related to the custom code, it should not be coming when I cleared the custom code. So Ideally something is wrong in some configuration only, But can't find anything.